# Maven: How to copy files to all subfolders of a folder

Tags: maven

I need to copy some specific files to all subfolders of a folder with maven.

Here is a sample folder structure to clarify my question. 
The initial folders like,

```
${basedir}
- A 
  - A1
    - file11.js
  - A2
    - file21.js
  - A3
    - file31.js
- TMP.js
```

Copy TMP.js to A1/A2/A3 folders. The expected result is like,

```
- A 
  - A1
    - file11.js
    - TMP.js
  - A2
    - file21.js
    - TMP.js
  - A3
    - file31.js
    - TMP.js
- TMP.js
```

Any advice?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you be more specific about the folders? Are they part of your maven project? At what point of the lifecycle do you want the files to be copied?

Comment: We're going to need more info. What files? Where? When? Is your project a JAR, a WAR? Are they resources?